# QGIS wrong measurments on Google satellite images

Tags: qgis-3, google-maps, accuracy, measurements

I am new to QGIS but I understand the basic principles. I'm working with QGIS 3.8.3 on OpenSUSE Tumbleweed Linux using the KDE environment.

Still trying to figure out QGIS, I'm opening a brand new project with default settings. I load Google satellite images in a layer and start measuring an area that I own and have exact measurements of. A 200 meter tree line is reported by QGIS to be 230 m, and another tree line 90 degrees to the first one is 210 m is reported by QGIS to be 240 m. These measurements are correct when using Google maps, so it's a QGIS setting issue.

Searching for answers I made sure that the project projection is WGS pseudo Mercator 3857 as this is supposed to be the projection of Google maps but it made no difference.

Any suggestions on how to set this up correctly?

Comment: After reading your post i conducted this experiment with Windows 10, QGIS 3.8.3:  I started with a new, empty project where the Project > Properties reported the CRS as EPSG:4326.  Then, using the Quick Map Services plugin, I loaded the Google satellite layer, which changed the Project Properties CRS to EPSG:3857, as expected.  Without loading any other layers, I then zoomed around the USA looking for (US) football fields.  Using the QGIS Measure line tool, they all correctly measured the fields at exactly 100 yards.  So, QGIS seems to be working ok for me.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Pseudo mercator (epsg 3857) is a terrible projection for making accurate measurements. Try a local projection (if in the US, choose a state plane projection)

Comment: Found the bug, but first, thank you @StuSmith for taking the time experiment. I recreated the project using QMS plugin, the projections are exactly as you described, but I still got the same error. Please check the screenshot: https://imgur.com/NHUG65d
The location in Egypt: https://goo.gl/maps/UNvBdJv8RwDBtmJA7
However, I though I'd try it on Windows. So I downloaded QGIS 3.10 on a Windows VM and guess what? The measurements are correct. I guess this is a Linux only issue or maybe even an issue with the openSUSE version. I will file a bug and see how it goes.